# Keras Image Classification on specific portion of image

Tags: python, keras, image-classification, mobilenet

Is it possible to perform image classification on a specific portion of images rather than a whole image?

I have an image Keras sequential image classifier where I give an image as input and it gives predictions. Is it possible to pass the location of an object in an image and get the predictions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand your scenario correctly, this is called object detection. Instead of classifying the entire image, it would predict a bounding box around a detected object. See more here: https://keras.io/examples/vision/retinanet/

Comment: And if the scenario is to classify a predefined bounding box, you could preprocess the image by cropping it to the area you'd like to get a prediction for, and use the same (or almost the same) keras model to predict this cropped image.

Comment: @Omri374 thanks for reverting back, I understand the cropped image path but is there an API in Keras which takes input the normalized rectangle and do the classification?